# In C#, what fires first, private member variables or constructors, and why?

Tags: c#, java

If I have a class like:

```
public class A
{
     public A(string name)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Mon");
     }
}

public class B
{
    private A m_a = new A("Tues");

    public B()
    {
        m_a = new A("Wed");
    }
}
```

I'm not on a windows machine so I can't test the output.

What would it be, but more importantly why is it that way?

i.e why would the private var get instantiated before the constructor, or visa versa.  Or would one be ignored or simply over-written?

Would Java be the same behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both C# and Java all the initialization that is outside a constructor comes before any calls to the constructor.  The assignment in the constructor would overwrite the other assignment.

For C# at least you can see the details of the [language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) in section 10.11.  That should answer any of the finer details of ordering, especially where inheritance is concerned.

Comment: would static constructors be called when you instantiate an object (if you have both types of constructors)?

Comment: @Blankman only on the first time an instance is created and if the static constructor hasn't been called yet.  From the spec: "The static constructor for a closed class type executes at most once in a given application domain. The execution of a static constructor is triggered by the first of the following events to occur within an application domain:
·         An instance of the class type is created.
·         Any of the static members of the class type are referenced."

Comment: where did you read that?  I can't seem to find a  link to the spec that you linked to (the actual spec), or do you have to download it?

Comment: @Blankman you have to download it from the page I linked to.  It downloads an HTML document.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how it works in Java (probably the same), but in C# member variables are instantiated before the constructor runs. As to why, I've never thought about it, and I don't know the best answer, but a pragmatic answer would be so that the member variables are available, already instantiated, in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Variable initializers (within the class) are called before the constructor for that class. So private `A m_a = new A("Tues")` would be called before `m_a = new A("Wed")`, because the constructor might need to use the values of the private variables. I would assume Java does it the same way, but I can't test it right now.

Answer (score 0):

As per the C# specification 17.4.5 Variable initializers:

> For instance fields, variable
>   initializers correspond to assignment
>   statements that are executed when an
>   instance of the class is created.

All fields also have default value initializers that run regardless of whether the field has a variable initializer:

> The default value initialization
>   described in 1.4.3 occurs for all
>   fields, including fields that have
>   variable initializers. Thus, when a
>   class is initialized, all static
>   fields in that class are first
>   initialized to their default values,
>   and then the static field initializers
>   are executed in textual order.
>   Likewise, when an instance of a class
>   is created, all instance fields in
>   that instance are first initialized to
>   their default values, and then the
>   instance field initializers are
>   executed in textual order.

So basically, there is no difference between private member initialization and construction initialization - the compiler will put it all the object's instance initialization routine, in textual order.